# Greasemonkey script to replace href

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

My html looks like this

```
<a class="jx_ui_html_a" target="_blank" __jx__id="___$_2854__a"      href="https://www.kitty.com">
<div class="jx_ui_html_div path_title" __jx__id="___$_2854__path"></div>
</a>
```

and

i am trying to find a greasemonkey script which changes the href part from ANYTHING to https://www.dog.com if the A class is jx_ui_html_a
so the result should be

```
<a class="jx_ui_html_a" target="_blank" __jx__id="___$_2854__a" href="https://www.dog.com">
<div class="jx_ui_html_div path_title" __jx__id="___$_2854__path"></div>
</a>
```

respectively

```
<a class="jx_ui_html_a" target="_blank" __jx__id="___$_28254__a" href="https://www.dog.com">
<div class="jx_ui_html_div path_title" __jx__id="___$_28254__path"></div>
</a>
```

Could you please help me in any way?

Answer (score 3):

The following is two lines of code - the first one queries the DOM to find all `a` tags (`document.querySelector('a')` and converts it into an array (by passing it as an argument to `[].slice.call`), and the second runs a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function on the array, which reassigns the `href` attribute of every DOM Element in the array.

```
var anchors = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a');
anchors.forEach(function(element){
    element.href = "http://www.dog.com/"
});
```

Same thing without forEach:

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for(var i=0;i<anchors.length;i++){
    anchors[i].href = "http://www.dog.com";
}
```

To limit the elements of `anchors` to only those with specific class name, supply it as part of the `querySelector` argument:

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a.jx_ui_html_a')
```

`querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` select elements the same way that rendering engines which apply CSS rules do. So you can pass it things like `"p > a"` (will return 'a' elements that are direct descendants of 'p' elements), and `"div#container span"` (which will return span elements that are anywhere inside the div with 'container' id).

`querySelector` returns the first match, while `querySelectorAll`  returns an array-like list of all matching elements.

Comment: Thanks Sidd. How can i incorporate only hunting for a with class="jx_ui_html_a"

Answer (score 1):

First you'll want to `require` jQuery. [You can read about how to do that here.](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Third-Party_Libraries). Once that's installed you can run something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.jx_ui_html_a').attr('href','http://www.dog.com');
});
```

In English, that will wait until the page is fully loaded (`$(document).ready()`), search for all elements with your specified class (`$('.jx_ui_html_a')`), and replace all of their `href` attributes with your specified URL.

Comment: <a href="http://www.cat.com" __jx__id="___$_3307__a" class="jx_ui_html_a" target="_blank"><div __jx__id="___$_3307__path" class="jx_ui_html_div path_title">Cats.</div></a> for example is not converted to dog.com